# ld: in /Users/.../Pods/..., building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/../Pods/FirebaseAnalyti

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, google-maps, apple-silicon

Trying to use pod for firebase in my code. Pod successfully installed but having this error.

I found that this error occured while compiling my swift code in macbook M1. Appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pod update` to update to a more recent version of Firebase. The default install has supported the M1 simulator since the 7.5.0 release.